# batch: how to pipe dir output to findstr?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to feed **findstr** with filenames without using the **/f** option, my script is like this:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%d in (.) do dir /b /a-d "%%d"
```

And I want to check if a specific string exist in each file displayed by the dir command.

Thank you

Comment: What's wrong with option `/F:/`?

Comment: @aschipfl I just don't want to use a file, I want to display all the files containing a specific string in one batch line, also I don't wan't to change the structure of my script (for...do dir...)

Comment: Why are you using the `/d` flag for your `for` if you're going to use `/a-d` in your `dir`?

Comment: Read the help of `findstr`; you will find that `/F:/` reads the list of files from the console, so you can pipe into the command: `dir /B /A:-D "%%~d" | findstr /F:/ "search strings"`. Actually I would not use the `for` loop at all and write it like this: `dir /B /S /A:-D | findstr /F:/ "search strings"`

Comment: @SomethingDark, since there is no wildcard in the set of `for`, there is no difference whether or not `/D` is specified; I would remove it though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the option `/F` and its special value `/`, which reads the list of files to search from the console rather than from a file:

```cmd
for /D /R %%d in (.) do dir /B /A:-D "%%d" | findstr /F:/ "search strings"
```

Since you are using the `for` loop just to return the directory tree, you could simply add switch `/S` to the `dir` command and dismiss the loop completely:

```cmd
dir /B /S /A:-D | findstr /F:/ "search strings"
```